# sort string array due to DayOfWeek

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, dayofweek

I have an string array

```
string[] days={ "1", "2", "6" }
```

I want to sort it according to `DayOfWeek` increasingly.
For example "1" is Monday, "2" is Tuesday,"6"is saturday. Today is Thursday.
So nearest one is Saturday,Monday,Tuesday. So final array will be

```
days={ "6", "1", "2" }
```

I couln't find any solution to sort them . How can I sort them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How these are nearest one `Saturday,Monday,Tuesday.`  of `Thursday`? What logic behind your **nearest one**?

Comment: You will have to write a custom IComparer.

Comment: I mean nearest day of today It will be sorted corresponfing to today Saturday is nearest day to today. Monday comes later, Tuesday comes later.@er-sho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is a bit complex to explain, so I use int instead.

Let the day-of-week always not smaller than today, then compare.

```
int[] days = { 1, 2, 6 };
int today;
Array.Sort(days, (d1, d2) =>
{
    if(d1 < today)
       d1 += 7;
    if(d2 < today)
       d2 += 7;
    return d1.CompareTo(d2);
});
```

---

Short form

```
Array.Sort(days, (d1, d2) => (d1 < today ? d1 + 7 : d1).CompareTo(d2 < today ? d2 + 7 : d2));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/QsVnIr

Comment: So, using `int.Parse` to get `int` out of `string` makes it complex how?

Comment: Do you see the adverb `a bit` ?

Comment: Nope, all I see is a bit strange excuse for not calling `int.Parse`, and as you may see all other given answer use `int.Parse` - your statement is a bit odd.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ for this:

```
string[] days = { "1", "2", "6" };

var today = (int)(DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7;

var result = days
    .GroupBy(x => int.Parse(x) > today)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => x));

Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", result));
# [6, 1, 2]
```

Which does the following:

1. Splits the before and after days into two groups
2. Sorts(descending) the after days *before* the before days
3. Sorts(ascending) each group

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want in-place sorting or not, but in case you don't want to change your array (or chain more processing to the array), then you can use LINQ to sort the array

```
var today = (int)DayOfWeek.Thursday;
int weekDays = 7;
string[] days = { "1", "2", "6" };
var sortedDays = days.Select(int.Parse).OrderBy(d => d > today ? d - today : d + weekDays - today);
```

You can use a similar logic in the `Array.Sort` method too, if you wish to go that route